# F5 Big IP prints an unknowed JS message

Tags: dns, f5

Here at the company we have a JSF 2.x project running on JBoss 6.2. However, on the border with the outside world, an F5 Big IP box started to give the following message in the browser to some of our customers. It's not about error itself, but for just a few hits.

```
(function(){var f5_cspm={f5_p:'LJDEOEPDEHLBLEFPEJJMFAAAFMFJLMEDFPCOKLCPLNKAFOBLBJLENGGNNANMMHKAFFCFJBIJODIBLJNCDCNJDOJBOLPAOLIPHJEGIGGCCNENNLKMADDAHHOFHMIIECMJ',setCharAt:function(str,index,chr){if(index>str.length-1)return str;return str.substr(0,index)+chr+str.substr(index+1);},get_byte:function(str,i){var s=(i/16)|0;i=(i&15);s=s*32;return((str.charCodeAt(i+16+s)-65)<<4)|(str.charCodeAt(i+s)-65);},set_byte:function(str,i,b){var s=(i/16)|0;i=(i&15);s=s*32;str=f5_cspm.setCharAt(str,(i+16+s),String.fromCharCode((b>>4)+65));str=f5_cspm.setCharAt(str,(i+s),String.fromCharCode((b&15)+65));return str;},set_latency:function(str,latency){latency=latency&0xffff;str=f5_cspm.set_byte(str,48,(latency>>8));str=f5_cspm.set_byte(str,49,(latency&0xff));str=f5_cspm.set_byte(str,43,2);return str;},wait_perf_data:function(){try{var wp=window.performance.timing;if(wp.loadEventEnd>0){var res=wp.loadEventEnd-wp.navigationStart;if(res<60001){var cookie_val=f5_cspm.set_latency(f5_cspm.f5_p,res);window.document.cookie='f5avr1940146702aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa='+encodeURIComponent(cookie_val)+';path=/';} return;}} catch(err){return;} setTimeout(f5_cspm.wait_perf_data,100);return;},go:function(){var chunk=window.document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/);for(var i=0;i
```

What's wrong? Google recaptcha can cause this message?

Recently we had problems with F5 DNS system and resolving requests. Maybe this can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The BIG-IP must have analytics enabled. See here: https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13849.

Comment: thanks; it was a npe exception unrelated to big ip. was solved.